# tf.data.Dataset: Map fails to split string

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a `tf.data.Dataset` that I've created like this:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({"reviews": x_train}, y_train))
```

I want to split just the reviews (strings) on whitespace.  When I do this:

```
dataset = dataset.map(lambda string: tf.string_split([string]))
```

Python complains, telling me:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I've looked at the docs and it's not obvious why Python thinks I've given two arguments...any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it has to do with the way `map()` is defined by tensorflow. Take a look at the docs here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map

`map()`'s signature:

> map(
>       map_func,
>       num_parallel_calls=None
>   )

The important bit is this:

> The input signature of map_func is determined by the structure of each element in this dataset.

So your `dataset` must somehow be arranged as elements of tuples of size 2 which makes `map` pass 2 arguments into `map_func`. However, you define your lambda function like:

```
lambda string: tf.string_split([string])
```

which means it expects 1 input, namely `string`.

Comment: ah got it.  My `x_train` is is a 2-d numpy array, so I tried `dataset = dataset.map(lambda string_dict, label: (tf.string_split([string_dict["sequence"]]), label))` but am told: `ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'StringSplit' (op: 'StringSplit') with input shapes: [1,1], []` . I think `string_dict["sequence"]` should point to a 2d numpy array?

Comment: Can you post a sample of what x_train looks like?

Comment: sure!  This is from Kaggle and it looks like this: `Complaint
0  I have outdated information on my credit repor...
1  I purchased a new car on XXXX XXXX. The car de...
2  An account on my credit report has a mistaken ...`

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a great idea of how it's formatted (what is `Complaint`?). Maybe you could update your answer with of a screenshot of the csv or json?

Comment: Please ignore the above.  The `x_train` numpy array looks like this: `[['I have outdated information on my credit report that I have previously disputed that has yet to be removed this information is more then seven years old and does not meet credit re']
 ['I purchased a new car on XXXX XXXX. The car dealer called Citizens Bank to get a 10 day payoff on my loan, good till XXXX XXXX. The dealer sent the check the next day. When I balan']
 ['An account on my credit report has a mistaken date. I mailed in a debt validation letter to allow XXXX to correct the information. I received']]`

Comment: Got it. So looks like you were getting the error in your first comment because you were passing a full tensor to `string_split`. You can solve that by just unpacking the tensor, i.e.: `dataset = dataset.map(lambda string_dict, label: (tf.string_split([string_dict["reviews"][0]]), label))`

Comment: But I'm not 100% sure why you want to create your dataset this way? `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({"reviews": x_train}, y_train))` will create a dataset where each row is a tuple with the first entry as a dict with one key, "reviews", and one value, a tensor with one entry -- the second entry is also its own tensor generated from whatever is in y_train? Intuitively, I don't see why you need to add in the dictionary if it will only have that one key, but I guess I don't know what you're creating downstream.

Comment: Ah, so if I just did `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))`, I could do `dataset = dataset.map(lambda string, label: (tf.string_split([string[0]]), label))`, right?

Comment: Yes, I think `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))` would simplify things for you. No need to introduce the dict as far as I can tell. The map call would become `dataset = dataset.map(lambda string, label: (tf.string_split(string[0]), label))`

Comment: Check here for a pretty good tutorial on using tensorflow `Dataset`s https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-dataset-in-tensorflow-c758ef9e4428

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182389/discussion-between-bclayman-and-killian95).